# How can we use different proxy port (other than 80 ) using Curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I would like to know, how can we use different proxy (other than port 80). like we have some proxy ip's from 3128,8080,3127,8008,8118 these ports. but we are unable to use these proxy in using cURL. Please suggest me proper way, in which we can use as many proxies from other ports  also. All the ip's from PORT 80 working fine.

Thanks

ROD

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 111.222.333.444);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$res['content'] = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

we are unable to use this proxyport here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `CURLOPT_PORT` and `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT` properties for [`curl_setopt()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: is this mentioned in my php.ini file

Comment: @Rodger curl config is done using the `curl_setopt` method as Crozin said ... there are no php.ini config options for curl -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php